# Issue in calling a Custom Html Helper from another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a Custom Helper Method called `DisplaySumForCompany` which looks like this:

```
public static class MvcExtension
{
   public static MvcHtmlString DisplaySumForCompany<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, int timeFrameTypeIndex, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, long definitionId, string popupHeader)
   where TModel : IKeyPush
    {
      // lines of code
    }

    // lines of code
}
```

I need to call this method from another Custom Helper method which I'm creating in the same class; I'm trying to call it like so:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ConstructCollapsibleColumns(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int columnIndex)
{
   // lines of code
   DisplaySumForCompany(0, x => x.Children[j].SummationNodeDetailList[model.Children[j].SummationNodeDetail(0).TimeFrameType].DiscreteItemsA, 0, "");
   // lines of code
    }
```

When I do this, I get the below error:
[image]

I believe this is because I'm not passing the 1st parameter(highlighted above) or in other words it is assuming the first parameter that I'm passing to be `htmlHelper`. My question is how do I pass it(if at all)? Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

**Note** that, the same call when I make from the View(cshtml) page, then there is no error:

```
@Html.DisplaySumForCompany(0, x => x.Children[j].SummationNodeDetailList[Model.Children[j].SummationNodeDetail(0).TimeFrameType].DiscreteItemsA, 0, "")
```

**Update**

When I try to pass `htmlHelper`as parameter viz `DisplaySumForCompany(htmlHelper, 0, x => x.Children[j].SummationNodeDetailList[model.Children[j].SummationNodeDetail(0).TimeFrameType].DiscreteItemsA, 0, "");`, it throws this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `htmlHelper` into the nested DisplaySumForCompany method as a parameter like below.

`DisplaySumForCompany(htmlHelper, 0, x => x.Children[j].SummationNodeDetailList[model.Children[j].SummationNodeDetail(0).TimeFrameType].DiscreteItemsA, 0, "");`

You can also call the extension method as you have an instance of the IHtmlHelper already e.g.

`htmlHelper.DisplaySumForCompany(0, x => x.Children[j].SummationNodeDetailList[model.Children[j].SummationNodeDetail(0).TimeFrameType].DiscreteItemsA, 0, "");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636674/richmercer it throws an error; I updated the same in my question

Comment: How about if you call it as an extension method? `htmlHelper.DisplaySumForCompany(0, x => x.Children[j].SummationNodeDetailList[model.Children[j].SummationNodeDetail(0).TimeFrameType].DiscreteItemsA, 0, "");`